# Need a Excel VBA loop code for copying and pasting a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, copy-paste

I want to make a loop for copying range A6 to B 2365 and pasting it 18 times below the previous range, i.e, I want to paste it right below the previous range so if the first range ends in row number 2365, I want the copied range to be pasted on row number 2366.

I did a macro recording and came up with the following code, but this only occurs 1 time, I want a code that can repeat this task 18 times.

```
Range("A6:B2365").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop to paste the copied range. Your code will be:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Range("A6:B2365").Select
    Selection.Copy

    For x = 1 To 18
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=15
    Next x

End Sub
```